# Can the coinbase transaction be used to spend an UTXO?

Tags: mining-reward, utxo

I know the coinbase transaction's input is usually just has a dummy `scriptSig`, but what if a miner used it to spend an UTXO? Would it be verified as an actual spend, or would the block be rejected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be rejected.  The coinbase input must use a very specific previous [outpoint](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format): `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff`. This prevents it from referring to an actual previous outpoint.